# How can we alter records inside trigger.new context variables

Tags: triggercontext

I have a small doubt that is,

How can we alter records inside trigger.new context variables

Please let me Know the answer ASAP

Thanks & Regards,
J Ramprasad

Comment: Hi Ramprasad - a point of etiquette: this forum tends to avoid answering questions that contain phrases like `..let me know the answer ASAP`. Polite, well-framed questions get quite rapid responses if you look at the history of responses in SFSE - no need to nudge us

Answer (score 2):

Simple modify the fields - only in BEFORE Triggers.

```
trigger example on Account(before insert){

   for(Account a : trigger.new)
       a.Name = 'I Changed You';

}
```

The values are modified from what they were when they entered the trigger.

This DOES NOT work in after triggers.

Comment: can we alter the After triggers?

Comment: Yes, but not like you are thinking. you have to query for the records and modify them then save them back taking care to identify recursion issues. Or use @future methods etc. But Specifically to your question, you CANNNOT modify trigger.new records in an after trigger